# Object level permission at ORM level in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-permissions

I have a Django application (mainly a rest API) with a completely custom User model (not inhered from Django). My authentication is based on JWT tokens.

I would like to make sure a user cannot access to data of another user. I have checked the django-guardian and django-rules. It provides stuff to call a has_perm function. However, in the case the developer does not perform the check and makes a mistake (for example hardcoding the user id in a query), a user might be able to access someone else data

Is there any way to enforce some kind of rule at the ORM level?

Comment: You might be able to use Database instrumentation, not however that I'm not certain this is a good practice for your use case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/instrumentation/